# Azure Active Directory Authentication to Azure Web Site

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, azure-web-app-service, windows-authentication

In my application, I am using Azure AD, I can login to application through azure AD, but sometimes when I enter the credentials then it will not redirect to the home page of my application and instead of that it redirects to the same login page. I have also configured the 'ReplyUrl' parameter on azure portal.

Does anyone has any idea about this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the reply url as the home page of the application with [Authorize] attribute on top of the home controller. And configure the application to move to the login page if the authorize fails so that the application moves to the home page if the authorization is correct.

Comment: localhost:8082/home/index can be configures

Comment: Hi Rijas, thanks for replay, I configured it already, but sometimes it authenticate and sometimes not. And when I restart the application from azure portal then it authentic the same user with same credentials.